# Entity Framework and IEnumerable

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have written a paging function that I had hoped would do an EF safe paging.  It seems though that this functions executes the EF query BEFORE paging, where as what I would like it to do is defer the paging to the database.  I thought IEnumerable would be safe but it appears it is not.  What is happening here?

```
private IEnumerable<T> PageList<T>(IEnumerable<T> list, PaginationOptions options)
{
    return list.Skip((options.Page - 1) * options.ResultsPerPage).Take(options.ResultsPerPage);
}
```

If I test this as a function vs the actual function called one generates SQL that contains the paging information and the other (the function) doesnt.

```
var pagedStuff = this.PageList(activities, options); // doesnt create correct query
var pagedStuff = activities.Skip((options.Page - 1) * options.ResultsPerPage).Take(options.ResultsPerPage);
```

P.s. I use IEnumerable as sometimes this function is used for normal Lists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I use `IEnumerable` as sometimes this function is used for normal `List`s

You may want to consider making an `IQueryable` overload as well:

```
private IQueryable<T> PageList<T>(IQueryable<T> list, PaginationOptions options)
{
    return list.Skip((options.Page - 1) * options.ResultsPerPage).Take(options.ResultsPerPage);
}
```

The problem is that since the input is an `IEnumerable`, the query is being executed *before* the paging is applied, so you get all records back and the paging is done in Linq-to-Objects.

Using `IQueryable` delays the execution of the query until *after* the paging is applied.

Comment: No need to change the method signature to `IQueryable` as it is `IEnumerable` as well.

Comment: @haim770 Yes it is, but the extension methods will be bound to `IEnumerable` (Linq-to-Objects) versus `IQueryable` (query provider).

Comment: And I didn't suggest _changing_ the signature, I suggested _adding an overload_

Comment: You changed the signature of the overloaded version. I think it only makes sense in case the OP is intending to chain further LINQ (to provider) calls to it.

Comment: @haim770 which is the point - if you call it on an `IQueryable` it will _still_ defer execution until the caller explicitly iterates the query or calls `AsEnumerable`

Comment: This is not always desirable. In the case of Repository, I'll almost always prefer to return `IEnumerable` or even materialize the query (using `ToList()` for example) upon return.

Comment: That's the caller's decision - all `Queryable` extension methods return an `IQueryable`.  If the caller wants to execute the query _after_ that then there are easy ways to do that.  You are suggesting _forcing_ execution which may not be desirable either (and impossible to prevent)

Comment: I only suggest forcing execution sometimes, depending on what the consumer of the API think it does. What if the consumer performs `data.Where(x => x.SomeMethod())` on the returned data? All I'm saying is that exposing `IQueryable` in API has to be a concise decision and the consumers have to be very aware of it.

Comment: I agree, but it's still _the caller's decision_.

Comment: I just noticed the OP method is actually `private` then in this particular case you're probably right anyway.

Comment: Just to clarify - What I actually do here is return IQueryable from all my repositories.  After reading your answers and discussions its clear to me that IQueryable signifies that execution could be deferred.  IEnumerable signifies that execution will happen immediately.  With this in mind I have changed the method signature to be IQueryable as per DStanley's answer although I appreciate your input @haim770

Answer (score 1):

You're invoking `IEnumerable.Skip/Take` instead of `IQueryable.Skip/Take`.

Try to use the `AsQueryable` method:

```
return list.AsQueryable()
           .Skip((options.Page - 1) * options.ResultsPerPage)
           .Take(options.ResultsPerPage);
```

Comment: If I call AsQueryable() on an IEnumerable that is in fact Queryable, does it have no performance hit?

Comment: No performance hit as it does nothing but `return data as IQueryable<T>`.

Comment: @haim770 the problem is that you get back an `IEnumerable` instead of an `IQueryable`.  The next Linq method that is called on the query will execute it (which may not be what the caller wants).